# In LightningChart-JS how to reverse the x-axis numbers from ascending to descending

Tags: lightningchart

I have a lineseries chart using LightningChart-JS, I need the x-axis numbers to be in descending order. The order of how the x,y points were added we're in descending order. Please help.

[test lineseries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sK5t8.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To invert the Axis, you can use [Axis.setInterval](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v3.0.0/classes/axis.html#setinterval).

```
chart.getDefaultAxisX().setInterval(1, -1)
```

As long as automatic fitting is enabled, the actual values don't matter.
Rather the key part is that the start value is higher than end value, resulting in inverted axis.